# Is it possible to use Drivine with expressJS? I've only seen NestJS examples

Tags: neo4j, drivine

I'm not entirely opposed to nest but I prefer to use express...

I'm aware that it's a pretty new framework, but it looks great and before I commit to switching over to NestJS on my project, I want to make sure that it's needed.